# SP2-0310: unable to open file "lab_05_01.sql"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

[image: The error is happening here.]

I have already checked the naming, it's completely fine. Can anyone help?
Thank You!

Comment: The SP2-0310 error occurs when you have not fully-qualified the PATH to the file.  Rather than rely on a variable, specify the fully-qualified path. 

SQL> @/u01/app/oracle./scripts/myfile.sql

Comment: still not working! same error

Comment: To solve this error, go to the related directory where the file exists and then invoke sqlplus and SQL Command file like ( lab_05_01.sql ).

Comment: "host cd" won't work as it will not change the working directory of running sqlplus client.
You can use absolute path: @D:\app\DBA\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\lab_05_01.sql
Or relative path: @?\BIN\lab_05_01.sql (if oracle_home is corrent).

Comment: still not working :(